# How to fix " Uncaught Reference Error: autobahn is not defined at HelloworldProxy.connect " error?

Tags: javascript, autobahn, franca

I am trying to implement franca IDL using js and autobahn on clientside and wamp c++ server.I am completely newbee to this .js this is the first time I am working on this but I have worked on franca with D-bus so I have idea on franca. Any help and suggestions will help ma a lot.

In clientside i wrote a simple helloworld code

```
package example.hello
  interface HelloWorld {
  version {major 1 minor 0}
  method sayHello {
    in {
      String name
    }
   out {
     String message
   }
  }
}
```

and generated the autobahn js binding code. Now am taking up the code as below but its showing the below error: 
 " Uncaught ReferenceError: autobahn is not defined at HelloworldProxy.connect "

hello.html code:

```
         <form>
   <br/><br/><br/>
        <label>Result: <output id="message" /></label><br/>
              <br/><hr/><br/><br/>

      <label>Status: <output id="connectionStatus"></output></label>
     </form>
         <p>This example uses WAMP communication to interact with a C++ 
    server using CommonAPI.</p>
      <br/><br/><br/><hr/>
     <form> 
<br/><br/><br/>
    <label>Result: <output id="message" /></label><br/>
            <br/><hr/><br/><br/>

    <label>Status: <output id="connectionStatus"></output></label>
</form>


 <script src="js/HelloworldProxy.js"></script>
<!--script src="js/HelloworldClientBlueprint.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
         console.log("I am alive!");
var proxy = new HelloworldProxy();
proxy.connect('ws://localhost:8081');
            //var clientId = 66;
    //var addr = 
'local:example.hello.helloworld:v0_1:example.hello.helloworld';

proxy.onOpened = function() {
    // your code goes here
 connection.onopen = function(session, details) {
            console.log("Connected", details);
            setStatus("Connected to network.");
};

  /**
  * Async callback in response to a 'sayHello' call.
   * 
   * @param cid the call id
   * @param message
    */
    proxy.replySayHello = function(cid, message) {
    // your code goes here
    };


/**
 * API function provided by the proxy for calling method 'sayHello'.
 * @param name
  */
    proxy.sayHello(name);


};

proxy.onClosed = function(event) {
// your code goes here
            connection.onclose = function(reason, details) {
            console.log("Connection closed", reason, details);
            setStatus("Disconnected.");
         }

};
setStatus("Connecting to server...");
         connection.open();
         function setStatus(text) {
            document.getElementById("connectionStatus").value = text;
         }

      </script>



  </body>
</html>

generated autobahn binding code:

function HelloworldProxy() {
    this.connection = null;
    this.session = null;
    this.address = 
"local:example.hello.helloworld:v0_1:example.hello.helloworld"
    this.callID = 0;
}

HelloworldProxy.prototype.getNextCallID = function() {
    this.callID = this.callID + 1;
    return this.callID;
};

  // call this method to invoke sayHello on the server side
       HelloworldProxy.prototype.sayHello = function(name) {
         var cid = this.getNextCallID();
         var _this = this;
       this.session.call(this.address + '.sayHello', [cid, name]).then(
        function (res) {
           if (typeof(_this.replySayHello) === "function") {
            _this.replySayHello(cid, res);
            }
       },
        function (err) {
            console.log("Call failed, error message: ", err);
            _this.replyError();
        }
    );
    return cid;
};

  HelloworldProxy.prototype.connect = function(address) {
     var _this = this;

_this.connection = new autobahn.Connection({
    url: address,
    realm: 'realm1'}
);

_this.connection.onopen = function(session, details) {
    console.log("Connected", details);
    if (typeof(_this.onOpened) === "function") {
        _this.onOpened();
    }

    _this.session = session;

    // subscribing to all broadcasts
}

_this.connection.onclose = function(reason, details) {
    console.log("Connection closed", reason, details);
    if (typeof(_this.onClosed) === "function") {
        _this.onClosed(reason);
    }
}

setStatus("Connecting to server...");
_this.connection.open();

     };
```

I need to connect the client with the server and get a response message from the server. The server is working good I have tested it with the help of RESTClint.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi it worked I just added the display functions in js and thus got output. 
similar to below code:

```
          document.getElementById("i1").onclick = function(){
          console.log("sending " + Indicator.R_ind);
          proxy.Myindicator(Indicator.name);

         proxy.replySayHello = function(cid, message) {
         document.getElementById("message").value = message;
         document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = message;
         };
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around and got the solution for above question. I was actually missing autobahn.min.js file (header file) from the autobahn. the connection has been achieved.It took half a day to reach this stage but it was a good experience.

Now the issue is I am not getting how to call the method sayhello in javascript to get the respose from the server.
i.e. : in javascript part I have

```
                 /**
                   * Async callback in response to a 'sayHello' call.
                   * 
                   * @param cid the call id
                   * @param message
                     */
                          proxy.replySayHello = function(cid, message) {
                              // your code goes here
                            };


        /**
     * API function provided by the proxy for calling method 'sayHello'.
       * @param name
     */
       proxy.sayHello(name);
```

I am not getting how to call these functions any suggestions will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.